# How to find dropping div children id?

Tags: jquery

I need to find the exact children id of droppable div. Now, currently it returns the parent element id. My Html

```
<div id="grey"  class="ui-widget-content">Goal #2:Even previously dropped objects should disappear when dragged to Grey area
    <div id="yellow" alignment="center" class="ui-widget-content">Dragged objects should stay</div>
    <div id="green" alignment="center" class="ui-widget-content">Dragged objects should stay</div>
</div>
```

So it always returns id as grey. How can i find the exact dropping div id.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GRDww/156/

Comment: where are you getting grey as the id?

Comment: Hi arun, What am trying to do is.After i drag and drop the box in yellow or green box. If move it outside in the grey area it should disappear. Now its get disappear even within the yellow box if i move.

Answer (score 0):

To get the dropping div id you should use

```
ui.draggable
```

inside the `drop` callback.

To get `id`:

```
console.log(ui.draggable.attr('id'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GRDww/157/

See console

https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: @divakar Check `console` to get the `id` of dropped element

Answer (score 0):

To get the draggable element ID:

```
ui.draggable.id
```

Or get the id of dropable element use:

```
event.target.id
```